# Instructions to spoof MAC address in OS X High Sierra not working

Tags: macbook, mac-address, ifconfig

I am following these instructions to spoof MAC address in High Sierra OS X:
https://blog.macsales.com/43777-tech-101-spoofing-a-mac-address-in-macos-high-sierra/

but I get unexpected errors such as:

```
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Device power is off
```

I get this error after I have powered off my wifi in accordance with the above documentation and subsequently run this command:

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether <new-mac-address>
```

the MAC address was generated with the `openssl` command from the documentation.

Why am I getting this error? It is unexpected based on what I am seeing on the docs.

Comment: The docs you linked do **not** tell you to power off your Wi-Fi. They tell you to disassociate from the network. Try it as written and see if it works. One caveat though: whoever wrote those instructions doesn't know MAC address structure/rules very well. You need to make sure you clear the 1's place bit and set the 2's place bit in the first octet. Their example of 9b in the first octet has the 1's place set, so it is a multicast address. They should have changed it to 9a.

Comment: @Spiff, thank you. This time I do not get an error, but unfortunately, I do not get the new MAC address appearing. When I do `ifconfig en0 | grep ether` after `sudo ifconfig en0 ether <openssl-generated-mac>`, I still get back the original mac address.

Comment: @Spiff, I am seeing people complaining on this apple forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106768, about it not working on a 2018 MacBook and/or High Sierra. I am on a mid-2015, High Sierra and here: https://mobile.slashdot.org/story/19/10/06/177216/did-macos-stop-allowing-changes-to-wifi-mac-addresses